# Ubuntu software center not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center

When I try to open software center, it gets closed within 5 seconds after being opened. I am not able to install or un-install any software using terminal too.
When I tried to uninstall Software center, the following was shown:

Reading package lists... Error!

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN

E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_*
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: @Abhijith you are welcome. If you like my answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you really like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark and the little up-arrow askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 

sudo apt-get clean all

sudo apt-get update
```

Hopefully that fixed your problem: